# Android studio how to forbid update dependencies in gradle

Tags: android-studio, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

Sometimes, I suppose when I change Project Structure or Edit Configurations, Android Studio automatically update dependencies in my build.gradle.

For example, it replaces

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1
```

with

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'`

After that some my options don't work and I should replace with old dependencies manually.

Is there a way to forbid this?

Comment: What exactly are you doing? I don't have such issue

Comment: Hm, unfortunately, I wasn't able now to reproduce this. Usually it happens after I add new module, test something in it, remove it from Project Structure, then Edit configurations. It didn't happen now, but already I faced this issue 4 or 5 times.